# How do I automate this sendinblue api?

Tags: python, django, sendinblue

Trying to automate the adding of contacts to sendinblue's api. The example given on their site shows adding a email and then adding it to a list in your account.

I have tried fstrings and .format(email, industry, role) but for some reason it keeps throwing back errors.

Heres what their website shows which works.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts"

payload = "{\"email\":\"someonesEmail97@gmail.com\",\"listIds\":[1,4],\"updateEnabled\":false}"
headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'content-type': "application/json"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers
```

Here's what I tried

```
import requests

url = "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts"

payload = "{\"email\":\f"{email}"\",\"listIds\":[f"{industry}",f"{role}"],\"updateEnabled\":false}"
headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'content-type': "application/json"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

I want this in the signup part of my site so it will grab their email thats been authenticated and add it to the appropriate list that I have set up. But what I get back from using fstrings is invalid syntax in the terminal pointing to the email field. 
I then tried .format and that didn't show any errors on the terminal but on the webpage I got this error back

```
payload = "{\"email\":\{}\",\"listIds\":[{},{}],\"updateEnabled\":false}".format(email, industry, role)
```

KeyError at /accounts/signup/activate/
"'email'" 
points to line that the payload is on.

What am I missing? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I get back from using fstrings is invalid syntax in the terminal
>   pointing to the email field

That's because you have quote mismatches, and you tried to create the f-string(s) in a weird, not valid way.

Try this:

```
payload = f'{{"email":"{email}","listIds":[{industry},{role}],"updateEnabled":false}}'
```

Comment: That's mainly because I'm weird and not valid. Thanks for that! Really appreciate the response it worked.

Comment: Didn't mean for it to sound like an insult. You are valid!

Comment: No I was joking :D really appreciate the help. No your valid!